# Show large value in exponent objective c

Tags: objective-c, math

Anyone have any idea to show large value in exponent form in objective?
e.g. 10000000000
What will the formula to show this number in exponent form.

Comment: Your number is `1e10`, but what exactly do you want to show where and why?

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes you are asking about [scientific e-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation).

If your goal is to convert the number `10000000000` to a string as `1e10` then use the `e` or `E` format specifier:

```
NSString *exponent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%e", 10000000000];
```

Use `%E` is you want a capital `E` instead of a lowercase `e` in the output.

And note that `%e` and `%E` can be formatted just like `%f` meaning you can specify the number of decimals, the total width, and whether leading spaces or zeros should be used as needed.

See [the full documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) for `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing: by "show" you mean convert to text format for display or printing.

If so then the two main ways to produce a textual representation for a numerical value are `stringwithFormat:` (& friends) and `NSNumberFormatter`.

The first of these provides a C `printf`-like facility. For example:

```
double val = 10000000000;
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", val];
```

will set `text` to the string `1e+10`. This example uses the `%g` format, there are others such as `%f`, and formatting such as the number of decimal places can be specified - for more details see the documentation.

The second provides an object-based facility. For example:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle;
NSString *text = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(val)];
```

will set `text` to the string `1E10`. There are other properties which can be set to control many aspects of the formatting, and `NSNumberFormatter` handles international differences in number formatting (like for those countries which use a comma (`,`) as the decimal fraction indicator rather then the point (`.`)). Again read the documentation.

HTH

Comment: Note that `%g` will show either the same as `%f` or `%e` depending on the value.